# Given an independent set of vectors {$v_1, v_2, v_3,v_4$} , then is {$v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1+2v_2, 2v_3-v_2$} dependent or independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given an independent set of vectors $\left\{v_1, v_2, v_3,v_4\right\}$ , then is $\left\{v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1+2v_2, 2v_3-v_2\right\}$ dependent or independent?

I've tried this:
$$\left\{v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1+2v_2, 2v_3-v_2\right\}$$

$$v_1+v_2+v_3+v_1+2v_2+2v_3-v_2=0$$

$$2v_1+2v_2+3v_3=0$$
The book says it's independent, but how can that be? If $3v_3=-2v_2-2v_1$.
Please any help is welcome.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Take an example, say in $\Bbb R^2$. Or in which vector space are we? Please give all details of the exercise.

Comment: How do you know that $v_1+v_2+v_3+v_1+2v_2+2v_3-v_2=0$?

Answer (score 3):

The rank of  the matrix
$$
 \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&1&0\\ 1&2&0&0
\\ 0&-1&2&0\end {array} \right]
$$
is $3$,  so the vectors are independent.

Comment: Or forget about $v_4$ and consider a square matrix, which will have nonzero determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x(v_1+v_2+v_3)+y(v_1+2v_2)+z(2v_3-v_2) = 0$

we get
$(x+y)v_1+(x+2y-z)v_2+(x+2z)v_3=0$, so

$x+y = 0,x+2y-z=0,x+2z=0$

When we solve this we get $x=0,y=0,z=0$
So they are independent.